# Button click not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm trying to do a click in a `html` button through `javascript`, but I can't make it work.

This is the button I'm trying to click with `javascript` (it works when I click it)

```
<button id="btnClean" runat="server" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-cons m-b-10" onserverclick="btnClean_Click">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    <span class="bold m-l-3">Limpar</span>
 </button>
```

This is the button that calls the `javascript` function:

```
<button id="btnCreateOS" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-cons m-b-10" onclick="Clean();">
    <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
    <span class="bold m-l-3">Criar</span>
</button>
```

And this is my `javascript` (it is located under `<form>` tag in my `.aspx` page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">        

    function Clean() {

        document.getElementById("btnClean").click();

    }

</script>
```

And finally, this is the `asp` method:

```
public void btnClean_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CleanFields();
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Any error in the console.

Comment: When you debug this, where/how specifically does it fail?  Are there any errors client-side or server-side?  Is the client-side function invoked?  Is the second button found by its `id`?  Is the post-back invoked?

Comment: move your javascript to after closing body tag

Comment: `document.getElementById("btnClean").click();` will call client event of `button`

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki got this error in console: Cannot read property 'click' of null at at HTMLButtonElement.onclick.

Comment: `onserverclick` != `onclick`. `btnClean` has the wrong event specified. Change it to `onclick`

Comment: @David when I click the button, nothing happens. The function isn't invoked.

Comment: @TechBreak can't do since the body tag in on master page and I'm using `asp:ContentPlaceHolder`

Comment: @Perozzo buttons are on content page?

Comment: @ADyson if I do this, when I click the button, nothing happens.

Comment: @RamSingh yes..

Comment: @Perozzo, i created sample application and added master page and content page and it is firing, let me share my code

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki got this error now on console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null`

Comment: @Perozzo, check my answer, it is working fine..

Comment: @Perozzo ah sorry that's because your `btnClean_Click` event is actually a server-side method. My mistake. Why not just give `btnCreateOS` the `onserverclick="btnClean_Click"` attribute as well, instead of having an intermediary javascript function? Or must `btnCreateOS` do other things in JavaScript as well beforehand?

Comment: @ADyson this is only an approach of what I really want to do. That's why I need it that way. And thank you so much for your help by the way.

Comment: @Perozzo, have you tried my solution???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bsically what happens, when you are using master and content page then it always changes its id according to it default behavior.

```
function Clean() {
        //document.getElementById("btnClean").click()

        document.getElementById('<%= btnClean.ClientID %>').click();
    }
```

Another solution you just add **ClientIdMode="Static"**.

```
<button id="btnClean" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-cons m-b-10" onserverclick="btnClean_Click">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
        <span class="bold m-l-3">Limpar</span>
    </button>
```

in your button..

Then your current javascript code will also work..

```
function Clean() {
        document.getElementById("btnClean").click();

        //document.getElementById('<%= btnClean.ClientID %>').click();
    }
```

Comment: Nice!!! Thank you so much for this! And thank you for your explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
document.getElementById("btnClean").trigger("click");
```

instead, because it's faster. Maybe you should also try to prevent default behaviour in btnClear_Click? Try to add a console.log("a") (or rather "b" at the second) to your two functions, to see, if and which of the two functions are running.

Comment: Got the same error in console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trigger' of null(…)`

Comment: 1) `.trigger` is a jQuery method, not native javascript. 2) Even if this worked, it would be semantically the same as OP's existing call to `click()`. 3) even if this worked, it would only trigger the client-side event of `btnClean`, which the button doesn't have - it has a server-side event which the OP is trying to call.